# How to Convert a Number into a String in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

I want to assign the current year then the next year. However, once I convert the current year to a number I'm not sure how to convert it back to a string. Any help is appreciated.

```
<#assign currentYear=.now?string('yyyy')>${currentYear} or <#assign 
nextYear=currentYear?number + 1>${nextYear}
```

Returns

```
2017 or 2,018
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this java or?

Comment: Yes Java Freemarker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did convert it back actually, you just don't want to do that with national formatting. `${nextYear?c}` will get rid of that. (BTW, maybe your example is simplification of something bigger, but if not, you don't need the 2nd assignment: `${(currentYear?number + 1)?c}`. Also, I think it's cleaner to apply `?number` in the first assignment, and then write `${currentYear?c}` and `${(currentYear + 1)?c}`.)

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

${(.now?string('yyyy'))?eval+1}
it will work

Comment: `?number` is faster than `?eval`... but the question was about converting the number to string. You might end up with `2,018` with this, depending on the current locale and `number_format` setting.